# Oracle query to extract data between 2 days for every month

Tags: sql, oracle

How to extract data between 2 days for every month. For example, say the date range is between 2nd and 10th. Then I need to extract data for 2nd and 10th of every month from the table.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: You need this query for two particular days of between two days? The title says the first, the last sentence here says the last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`EXTRACT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm)

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  EXTRACT( DAY FROM date_column ) BETWEEN 2 AND 10;
```

or `TO_CHAR` then `TO_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( date_column, 'DD' ) ) BETWEEN 2 AND 10;
```